# Angular 2 - import of external leaflet typescript definition

Tags: angular, webpack, leaflet

I've the same question like this one:
[Angular 2 - import of external leaflet typescript library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375749/angular-2-import-of-external-leaflet-typescript-library)

But since Angular 2 is using Webpack now, How to include 'leaflet' using angular-cli and webpack configuration.

Comment: Hey @Ahmed Hashem Have you found how to include leaflet?

Comment: Hey @Bernhard.. Did you solve it or you still need an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

1- In `package.json` make sure you've added `@types/geojson`, `@types/leaflet`, and `leaflet` packages:

```
"dependencies": {
......
"@types/geojson": "0.0.31",
"@types/leaflet": "^1.0.40",
"leaflet": "^1.0.2",
.......
}
```

or simply add them by: `npm install @types/geojson @types/leaflet leaflet --save`

2- In `angular-cli.json`file spot `"styles"` and add `leaflet.css` to it:

```
"styles": [
  .....
  "../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
],
```

3- Make sure that `tsconfig.json` in your angular-cli project have a reference to the `@types` folder:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "../node_modules/@types"
]
```

4- Now, `leaflet` is available in the angular-cli project and you can use it by referencing the `L` namespace:

```
map: L.Map;
mapOptions: L.MapOptions;
```

Comment: Hey @Ahmed Hashem is there any chance you could you give a more detailed example of how step 4 works such as an example component?

Comment: @NickCrawford .. I'll make a plunk and share it

Comment: Were you able to make a plunk? Thanks. Did you get anything working with some 3º parties libraries as leaflet markercluster or smililar?

Comment: @NickCrawford did you came up the solution code for step 4